# Dispaly a text on textblock in every 10 seconds of video playing using MediaElement

Tags: video, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal, mediaelement

I'am playing a video using MediaElement. To get the total duration of selected video, I'am using MediaOpened event. Now I want to display a text on every 10 second of video. How is it possible?Is there any event while playing video?

```
  <Button Content="Select Video" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Button_Click"/>
  <MediaElement Name="videoMediaElement" MediaOpened="videoMediaElement_MediaOpened" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="tb_display_roadname" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

 private async void videoMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // bool isLive = IsLiveStream(sender as MediaElement);
        var totalDurationTime = videoMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    }
  private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        foreach (string extension in FileExtensions.Video)
        {
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(extension);
        }
        file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        // mediaPlayer is a MediaElement defined in XAML
        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            videoMediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);       
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement#Events) shows the following available events and I think they are not what you need. You can create a [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) here yourself and show or hide your text which is overlay the mediaelement.